# How to get smooth square root of complex valued function?

Tags: function-construction, complex

Let $f(x)$ be smooth complex valued function with real argument $x\in[0,1]$.
I want to get square root $g(x)=\pm\sqrt{f(x)}$ where the sign is chosen so that g(x) is smooth. How can I do that?

In Mathematica, the branch cut of square root is on negative reals. Thus, for example, I want to flip the sign if $f(x)$ cross negative reals in complex plane when $x$ increases.

Comment: Something like this? `Plot[Sign[x]*Sqrt[Abs[x]], {x, -5, 5}]` https://imgur.com/0FoXmC1

Comment: Are you OK with your "square root" giving different values for different arguments?  For example, if $f(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$, then I think you're forced to have $g(x) = e^{i \pi x}$.  But this would mean that $g(0) \neq g(1)$, even though $f(0) = f(1)$.

Comment: More generally, if $f(x)$ "winds" around zero as $x$ ranges from 0 to 1, I think you'll be forced to either accept a discontinuity in $g(x)$ or have a multi-valued square root.

Comment: Thank you for a comment. Yes, I'm okay with that. I just want to construct smooth $g(x)$ and don't care $g(0)\neq g(1)$. If it's problematic, then let's concentrate on the case "winding number" of $f(x)$ around zero is  even number.

Comment: Got it.  So the goal is to construct a smooth complex-valued function $g(x)$ such that $g^2(x) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be reduced (I think) to the problem of defining a phase function $\arg(f(x))$ that is continuous on the interval $x \in [0, 1]$.  This is tricky, because the path $f(x)$ may "wind" around the origin, leading to different values of the "continuous argument" for the same value of the "conventional argument".  A successful "continuous argument" function will need to "keep track of the history" of the function $f(x)$, so that it "knows" whether the phase along the positive real axis should be $0$, $2 \pi$, or something else.

One way to do this is to note that although the conventional `Arg` function is discontinuous along the negative real axis, its derivative is continuous.  Specifically, since $\arg(f(x)) = \Im \ln(f(x))$, we have
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \arg(f(x)) \right] = \Im \left[ \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right].
$$
We can treat this as a differential equation for $\arg(f(x))$;  if we integrate it, we'll get a "continuous argument" function.
$$
\tilde{\arg}(f(x)) \equiv \arg(f(0)) + \int_0^x \Im \left[ \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \right] \, dt.
$$
With this in hand, we can then define
$$
g(x) = \sqrt{|f(x)|} e^{i \tilde{\arg}(f(x))/2}
$$
and this function will be continuous.

---

#### Implementation:

I will test this function on $f(x) = e^{4 \pi i x}$.  Difficulties may arise for more complicated functions, particularly those which have roots where $f(x) = 0$.  (However, I believe that no smooth $g(x)$ can be defined in such cases anyhow.)

**Continuous argument function:**

```
contarg[f_] :=
  Arg[f[0]] + Integrate[Im[f'[t]/f[t]], {t, 0, #}] &;
f[x_] = Exp[4 \[Pi] I x];
Plot[{Arg[f[x]], Evaluate[contarg[f][x]]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Continuous square root:**

```
contsqrt[f_] := Sqrt[Abs[f[#]]] Exp[I contarg[f][#]/2] &
contsqrt[f][x]
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[contsqrt[f][x]]], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[Sqrt[f[x]]]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]

(* E^(2 I \[Pi] x) Sqrt[E^(-4 \[Pi] Im[x])] *)
```

[image]

[image]

For more complicated functions $f(x)$, Mathematica may not be able to perform the integral required to evaluate `contarg[f][x]`.  In such cases, you may have to resort to using `NIntegrate` instead.

Comment: I'm happy for the very clear idea and grateful for showing precise implementation. Thank you so much!