# Choose branch cut of sqrt so that function is continuous?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am willing to plot the following function

`Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[Conjugate[Sum[w^k*Exp[(1/2)*(Conjugate[w^k]*(x + I*y) - w^k*(x - I*y))]*Sum[w^k*Exp[(-2^(-1))*(Conjugate[w^k]*(x + I*y) -w^k*(x - I*y))], {k, 0, 2}],{k, 0, 2}]]]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]`

The issue then is that Mathematica induces a branch-cut of the square root function so that the above function becomes discontinuous. Is there a way to plot this function so that the graph becomes continuous and smooth?[image]

Comment: Related:  [How to get smooth square root of complex valued function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226731/)  However, that question had more to do with a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ while this one appears to be $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$.  I suspect that will make things more difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: Also, you should provide a definition of `w` if you want people to be able to reproduce & modify your code.

Comment: Try the option `ExclusionStyle->`